# Java Spring boot Sql Database design

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, database-design

I have some issues in designing the database.

Requirement :

1)There will be one  central admin who adds the reports and they should be visible to the user if they belong the particular place only.

Scenario : let's imagine Central admin have added ABC report. 
1)One of the user have logged  from X place in he must see the report ABC and he will upload the some file and submit. His status is changed to submitted.
2)One more user have logged  from Z place he should also see the  ABC report . 
3)Other user logged from Y. He should not see the report.

Question : how I can mapped the reports table  to the  place table and maintain the user  file status where they have uploaded the file or not, according to the place.

Problem : With current implementation I am inserting data into database (mysql) like this. 
If ABC report is applicable for X and Z place. There is one more table where I save user details like he have uploaded the file or not. 
ReportName.      Place Id 
1)ABC                      1(X)
2)ABC.                      2(X)

Comment: It is currently quite hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Please clearly state you requirements first and then add your implementation attempts. Also please make sure that we understand what are you actually asking.

Comment: "*...there are around 600 theaters...*" - ... What?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for replying I am sorry you guys didn't understood my problem. I have elaborated now.